# How to send Javascript array object to the MVC5 controller method

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

Hi below is my question.
How to send Javascript array object to the MVC5 controller method.

The code successfully hit the action method but the list value param value is null.  I tried different combination with the JSON.stringify as well.

```
    //object class
    public class  MassPayoutItem
        {
           public string ReciverEmailID { get; set; }
           public string Amount { get; set; }
           public int ProviderID { get; set;}
           public string AppintmentsID { get; set; }
           public string TransictionID{get;set;}
           public string TransictionStatus { get; set; }
           public string ProviderName { get; set;}
        }

    //Action method
     public ActionResult GetProviderMassPaymentDetail(List<MassPayoutItem> PayoutItemList){
      return Json(new { Result = true, ResultData = ResaultData, Message = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }


    //JavaScript Code
    function MassPay() {
                alert("called MassPay");
                var MassPymentList = new Array();
                var objs;
                $('.Include_Payment:checked').each(function () {

                    var ReciverEmailId = $(this).parents('tr').attr("emailid");
                    var appointmentids = $(this).parents('tr').attr("appointmentids");
                    var ProviderID = $(this).parents('tr').attr("UserId");
                    var Amount = $(this).parents('tr').find(".Amount").text();
                    var ProviderName = $(this).parents('tr').find(".OwnerName").text();
                    MassPymentList.push({ "ReciverEmailID": ReciverEmailId, "Amount": Amount, "ProviderID": ProviderID, "AppintmentsID": appointmentids, "ProviderName": ProviderName, "TransictionID": "abc", "TransictionStatus": "bcd" });
                });
                objs = JSON.stringify({ "PayoutItemList": MassPymentList });
                         debugger;

// _PageUrl.PayMassTransiction 
// '@Url.Action("GetProviderMassPaymentDetail","Controller")'            
//The call hits the method but the value is null
                $.ajax({
                    Type: "POST"
                    , url: _PageUrl.PayMassTransiction
                    , contentType: "application/json,charset=utf-8",
                    traditional: true
                   , data: objs,
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        debugger;
                        alert("called");
                    }
                    , error: function (result) {

                    }
                });

            }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the js object be in an array?

Comment: Kyle i am not getting your point can you elaborate please your answer by modifying the code if something is wrong there.

Comment: I think that `objs = JSON.stringify(MassPymentList);` would suffice

Comment: I try  objs=JSON.stringify(MassPymentList); it sending the null value.

Comment: Have you allowed POST on the controller action?

Comment: I try to put [HttpPost] it show 404 error resource cannot be found.

Comment: Thanks  Kyle for help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Finally I solve the issue.

```
 public class  MassPayoutItem
        {
           public string ReciverEmailID { get; set; }
           public string Amount { get; set; }
           public int ProviderID { get; set;}
           public string AppintmentsID { get; set; }
           public string TransictionID{get;set;}
           public string TransictionStatus { get; set; }
           public string ProviderName { get; set;}
        }

    //Action method
    **//This is first change i have make.**
      [HttpPost, ActionName("GetProviderMassPaymentDetail")]
     public ActionResult GetProviderMassPaymentDetail(List<MassPayoutItem> PayoutItemList){
      return Json(new { Result = true, ResultData = ResaultData, Message = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }


    //JavaScript Code
    function MassPay() {
                alert("called MassPay");
                var MassPymentList = new Array();
                var objs;
                $('.Include_Payment:checked').each(function () {

                    var ReciverEmailId = $(this).parents('tr').attr("emailid");
                    var appointmentids = $(this).parents('tr').attr("appointmentids");
                    var ProviderID = $(this).parents('tr').attr("UserId");
                    var Amount = $(this).parents('tr').find(".Amount").text();
                    var ProviderName = $(this).parents('tr').find(".OwnerName").text();
                    MassPymentList.push({ "ReciverEmailID": ReciverEmailId, "Amount": Amount, "ProviderID": ProviderID, "AppintmentsID": appointmentids, "ProviderName": ProviderName, "TransictionID": "abc", "TransictionStatus": "bcd" });
                });
                objs = JSON.stringify({PayoutItemList: MassPymentList });
                         debugger;

// _PageUrl.PayMassTransiction 
// '@Url.Action("GetProviderMassPaymentDetail","Controller")'            
//The call hits the method but the value is null
// below is the changed ajax calll change Type to type               
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST"
                , url: _PageUrl.PayMassTransiction
                , contentType: "application/json,charset=utf-8"
                ,async: false
            ,traditional: true
               , data: objs,
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    alert("called");
                }
                , error: function (result) {

                }
            });
            }
```